# NOIP2 process is crashing on start Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, ubuntu-10.10

I'm configuring my **Ubuntu 10.10 box** and one of the things that I add to my: `/etc/rc.local` is a command to start my [no-ip.org](http://www.no-ip.com/) updater.

---

But, I saw that this process is not getting started up. While checking the [`dmesg`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg) I observe erros, and I need a hand to find why this is happening:

```
$ dmesg |grep -i noip
[ 1486.329369] noip2[1432]: segfault at 65382538 ip 0013ecc4 sp bf85c044 error 4 in libc-2.12.1.so[110000+157000]
```

---

Observations:

- I can start this same ShellScript that start noip2 by hand and all works
- The command to start the noip2 is quite simple:
- `/home/user/dev/noip-2.1.9-1/noip2 -c config.properties`

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to write an init script for it in /etc/init.d